# Calculate duration when boolean field is true in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, duration

I have the following table in a MySQL database, which records when a system was on or off. Data is currently acquired every ten minutes, but this may change in future.

```
timestamp              on                   
2014-12-29 07:59:59    1
2014-12-29 08:09:59    1
2014-12-29 08:20:00    1
2014-12-29 08:29:58    0
2014-12-29 08:39:59    1
2014-12-29 08:49:59    1
2014-12-29 08:59:58    0
2014-12-29 09:09:59    0
2014-12-29 09:19:58    0
2014-12-29 09:29:59    0
2014-12-29 09:39:58    1
2014-12-29 09:49:59    0
```

I am currently doing some processing in `pandas` in Python to calculate the duration of time that the system has been on for. I do this by getting the points at which the status changes, and then calculating the duration between these times.

Is there a way to do this in SQL? If possible I'd rather do it in the database, particularly as I could then do it for each day over a period of time without transferring all of the data to the client. In `pandas` I used the `shift()` function to get the next row and see if it is different, but I can't see a way to do that in MySQL.

Any ideas?

SQL to set up a table with the example data above is available at https://gist.github.com/robintw/abc9a33d54c1d40c6f01

Comment: Please edit your question with your desired results.

Comment: Please don't name columns after reserved keywords... Your column "On" clearly conflicts with the SQL commands `JOIN ON`, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, etc.

Comment: This is admittedly not a great nor technical answer, but if you're actually pulling the status every 10 minutes, you could multiply the count of on's by 10 minutes each.